# Unable to start handle detector

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am not able to start the handle detector.
When I run the handle localization: $ roslaunch handle_detector localization_sensor.launch I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf2::LookupException'
what():  "base" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist. 
[localization-1] process has died [pid 2931, exit code -6, cmd /home/christina/catkin_ws/devel/lib/handle_detector/handle_detector_localization __name:=localization __log:=/home/christina/.ros/log/fb4cc224-2aba-11e5-97ce-080027e4fc6e/localization-1.log].   log file: /home/christina/.ros/log/fb4cc224-2aba-11e5-97ce-080027e4fc6e/localization-1*.log    all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit    shutting down processing monitor...                                                                     ... shutting down processing monitor complete                                                          done
```

I have no idea to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213746/unable-to-start-handle-detector/) by [cP](https://answers.ros.org/users/23185/cp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have a coordinate system (frame) called `"base"` in your robot model.
This is actually hardcoded in the `handle_detector_localization` node, so it cannot be set via a parameter.

Check whether your robot has a frame called `"base"`, otherwise you need to add one.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on 2016-07-27**:
I'm running with the turtlebot...
I'm doing roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch //to bring up the kinect v2
And running into the same error.

How do I add 'base' to the robot model?